# I have to create a link between the original row and the updated row when inserting a duplicate row

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008, sql-server-2005

Suppose I need to duplicate the following

```
CustID    FName     SName
1234      Mike      Smith
```

after the insert it would be

```
CustID    FName     SName
1235      Mike      Smith
```

I need to create a temporary link between both existing and new records.
When I do the insert it would be good to have a temp table with

```
ExistCustID   New CustomerID
1234          1235
```

By doing this I would be able to link the old to the new, this is what I need to do, but it needs to be done for multiple row insert.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just use the `SCOPE_IDENTITY()` to `SELECT` the newly created ID, then use this to `INSERT` into the link table:

```
-- The Customer you're duplicating
DECLARE @CustID INT
SET @CustID = 1234

-- Insert the copy record
INSERT INTO Customer (FName, SName)
(SELECT FName, SName FROM Customer WHERE CustID = @CustID)

-- Get the last newly inserted ID in the current scope
DECLARE @NewCustID INT
SELECT @NewCustID = SCOPE_IDENTITY()

-- Insert the link record
INSERT INTO [YourLinkTable] (ExistCustID, NewCustomerID)
VALUES(@CustID, @NewCustID)

-- Or if you're updating the master record
UPDATE Customer 
SET NewCustomerID = @NewCustID
WHERE CustID = @CustID
```

Comment: Hi, this is exactly what I want to do however this plan is based on one customer being inserted,I actually need to do the same thing but for a multiple row insert.

Comment: @PaulGilfeather you could wrap the above code in a cursor to iterate over each row in the results to be updated

Comment: This is true but I would ideally like to avoid using the cursor for obvious reasons, however if this is what is boils down to I will do it.

Comment: @PaulGilfeather obvious reasons?

Comment: Also, I know if I persevere there is another way

Comment: So when copying do you want to update the parent record or child record with the link?